# Programar tarea por tiempo en Laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, websocket

Tengo un sistema de Pedidos. Cada pedido tiene una vigencia de 3 días, después de esos 3 días, sino no han pagado el pedido, debe desaparecer del carrito.
El problema que tengo, es que no se como ó donde pudiera programar algo que escuche el tiempo de vida de cada pedido y ejecutarlo de manera automática.

Mi proyecto lo estoy haciendo con Laravel 7.0 y Postgres 9.2

Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos!!!

Comment: Puedes hacer Task Scheduling https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que puedes crear un comando que revise el tiempo que lleva el pedido. Luego ese comando lo ejecutas periódicamente con la función schudule del kernel.php. Esto es dentro de la carpeta app/console/commands.

Tal vez esto te ayude a encontrar inspiración https://medium.com/@cvallejo/cronjobs-laravel-585017b32862, ignora lo de los correos.

Answer (score 0):

Un cronjob es la respuesta ideal:

```
* * 3 * * <command to execute>
```

Así te ejecuta el cron cada 3 días.

Más información:
https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/